# procedural time difference between SQL and PHP

Tags: php, sql, performance

Could someone tell what is the average percentage of speed difference of SQL over PHP or the opposite.
By "speed difference" I mean during the process of manipulating data.

I have to manage a website with a huge database, It's the first time I deal with a huge database like that.
My knowledge of PHP is ten times better than my SQL one if comparable. For this reason I've always manipulated the data from my PHP scripts.

For instance, I decided to use a class to store data of pictures from the table "picture".
Using PDO and the fetchMode FETCH_CLASS, I can manipulate the fetched data from the constructor. One field is the size of the picture in a string type like "widthxheight". In my constructor I use a split method to store the two properties in separate variables.
Since there is a lot of rows, I'd like to know if this splitting would be preferable to be performed directly from the fetch statement of the SQL code.

let's assume i have more than 10k rows, would that change be effective ? or can I stick with PHP for this purpose ?

Comment: Width/height should be two separate int columns, not a single string with a magic value! If you need the string value, create *that* inside your php class, not the other way around!

Comment: If i were the designer of the table, I would have done that :-)

Comment: It should be built like @FrancisAvila is describing. For example, Using your current method try to query out all images that have a height or width above 1024.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hard and fast rule here. Some operations will be much faster in SQL, some will be faster in PHP, and the speed difference will vary wildly.

The scenario you describe should not make a big difference either way, so you should do it in whatever way makes for the most understandable and maintainable code. (Probably in PHP, as you are doing it now.)

However, the way the width and height is stored in the DB is terrible and wrong. If this is characteristic of the database design you have to deal with, expect to be working around some brokenness.

Answer (score 2):

I think in your case it will be a huge difference:

You select N rows. You change one value in ervery single row. This will result in N update queries with maybe N transactions.

If you definde one update query, you can update N rows within one statement and one transaction.

That will be faster.

Comment: Am I missing something? I took the question, given his example, to mean "should I split this value (`widthxheight`) in sql or php when I query it out of the database?" Of course doing updates on multiple rows will be better than updating one row at a time. But there isn't a single "update" in the post/example.

Comment: splitting in PHP is slower, as mentioned above, compared to 'UPDATE my table set width=substr(withheight, 0,2)' height=substr(withheight, 3,2)'

Comment: I don't have the SQL command for find position of 'x', so I assumed hard positions for x.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there would be enough of a difference to matter. However know that in sql, this would be several function calls to replicate the split functionality (find the Nth delimeter and substring between that and the next instance of delimeter) as sql doesn't have a split function and doesn't support multiple values in a column. And it would have to be done for every column. If the values were comma separated you could use find_in_set, but still multiple function calls.

Comment: Was the question about split one value while reading in PHP vs. SQL? Thought it was about modifing lots of rows.